# Eclipse Java - Running FIle issues; Im new around here

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

I have the following code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Renderer;
import javax.swing.Timer;


// All packages imported , ready for use... Add more if need be : +



@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class main implements KeyListener, ActionListener 
{
    public boolean board_show =true;
    public int AOB1 = 16;
    public int AOB2 = 16;

    public static int WOB = 640;
    public static int HOB = 640;

    public int GStat = 0;
    // Defines when game is playing, toggle-able twice 0, 1, 2
    // 0 = Menu, 1 = Paused, 2 = Game
    // Might Become Redundant
    // TODO Make this feature redundant!


    public boolean click, space;
    public int turn;
    public Component renderer;


    public void ScreenUp()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("CHESS");

        jframe.setSize(WOB, HOB);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.add(renderer);
        jframe.addKeyListener(this);



        timer.start();


    }

    public static void render(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WOB, HOB);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And I want to know why Eclipse, my editor will not let me run this file, as a whole, even in other modes it comes up with errors. I am fairly new to Java, so I am trying to make a Game - Chess. For now I just want to know why the editor will not let me run it and how I can run it. And of course, since I am new to Java, I only know the basics of the language, so any detailed response would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are missing the main method...(check GhostCat's answer)

Comment: Beyond that: you also want to read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, and "_" is "reserved" for SOME_CONSTANT; you would name that thing `boolean showBoard` instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect that having a class named `main` is enough to define an entry point to *run* a Java application. Wrong.

You need  a method with exactly this signature

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

in your class. That method defines what happens when you "run" the class/application.

And the real answer is: study those tutorials written for people ... that just "start" with Java, like the one from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html). Even when you are proficient in other languages - when you just *assume* how things work; chances are that you run into exactly this kind of problems.

Comment: Ugg, I don't know about that last comment, but thanks!

Comment: Sorry, now that I reread your last sentence I get what you mean, but seriously, that's just an unnecessary step that with refining, could be change by the developers??? Probs. not... thanks!

Comment: And with ur last paragraph, I already know how to code in python quite proficiently, and with all respect, I've always been for the text-base coding rather than visual like Flash or Scratch

Comment: Still: order is important. You just ran into some wall; because you missed an essential "newbie" detail. So in the end, this is about efficiency. As a pro, you might be able to read through those tutorials quickly. But you should **still** read them "in order", to not miss such subtle but important details. Nonetheless, I reworked my answer.

Comment: With a little bit of fiddling, I managed to fix the error that occured, so I thank you very much

Comment: You are very welcome. Have fun exploring java. May the upvotes be with you.